# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' with certain passwords only

Tags: mysql

I just setup a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 with MySQL 5.6.19.  After completing the installation I executed `mysql_secure_installation` which walked me through some security settings AND had me set a root password.  My root password currently contains @ and $ symbols.  When I try and execute

```
mysql -u root -pAP@$$Here
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

**Why am I getting this error?**

If I run `mysql_secure_installation` on the command line again and change the root password by removing the @ and $ symbols I am able to connect in just fine when I run

```
mysql -u root -pAPassHere
```

On related but separate issue, I also tried to connect by issuing the command:

```
mysql -u root
```

I was expecting to be prompted for the password, but instead I got the following related error

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

**Why am I not being asked for a password?**

Comment: Are you sure the first error message is what is returned when you specify the password on the command-line? Particularly the piece that says "using password: NO"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that some symbols like `$` have special meaning in the shell, and the shell expands variable into their values before passing the string to the program.

For example, try this:

```
$ echo AP@$$Here
AP@6282Here
```

The `$$` is replaced with the process id of the bash shell from which I ran this command. If you want to suppress variable expansion, put the string in single-quotes:

```
$ echo 'AP@$$Here'
AP@$$Here
```

This works with the MySQL client too:

```
$ mysql -u root -p'AP@$$Here'
```

Note that you must still have no space between `-p` and the quoted password.

You can also get the MySQL client to prompt you interactively by using `-p` with no string following:

```
$ mysql -p
Enter password:
```

Finally, it may be convenient for you to enter your password in your $HOME/.my.cnf and then you won't have to type it. This also bypasses shell variable expansion, and takes the value from the config file literally.

```
$ cat >> $HOME/.my.cnf
[client]
user = root
password = AP@$$Here
^D
```

Answer (score 2):

`$$` will be interprepted by the shell as a variable ($$ will return the PID of the current process I think) so you'll want to surround your password in quotes like:

```
mysql -uroot -p 'foo$$bar'
```

to be prompted by the password (a more secure option as it won't be stored in your shell's history) connect specifying the password flag but with no value:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

and then you'll be prompted for the password

Comment: Thank You James.  This answer was correct and helpful!

Answer (score 0):

you'll only get prompted for a password with the -p switch without anything following it. try wrapping your username and passwords with `"` and using something like this:

```
mysql --user=root --password="AP@$$Here"
```